# Why the PostgreSQL rule condition is not being respected?

Tags: postgresql, rules

Consider the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id int primary key, test text);
CREATE TABLE test_hist(id serial, id_test int, test text);
```

I've created the following rules:

```sql
CREATE RULE test_ins AS ON INSERT TO test WHERE exists (SELECT id FROM test WHERE test.id = new.id) DO INSTEAD UPDATE test SET test = NEW.test WHERE id = NEW.id;

CREATE RULE test_upt AS ON UPDATE TO test  DO ALSO INSERT INTO test_hist(id_test, test) VALUES (old.id, old.test);
```

Why when I insert an entry into `test` it is "executing" the `update` too? When I perform an `insert` an entry is being inserted in the `test_hist` as well.

If I create a rule like this:

```sql
CREATE RULE test_ins AS ON INSERT TO test WHERE exists (SELECT id FROM test WHERE test.id = new.id) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

It works as expected, doing nothing. Is it inserting and then checking the condition on the rule?

My initial idea was to use `ON CONFLICT` for inserts, but it can't be performed when a rule exists for update or insert (why is that?).

Comment: When you attempt to create a test record whose id already exists, it updates instead according to your first rule. Are you sure your inserts did not provide an id which already exists? This could happen on concurrent access scenarios.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm trying this in the cli... It is not even an app yet... And yeah, the idea is to update if the key already exists. And when an update happens, the old entry goes to the history table. The thing is if you create this tables and insert a new entry, it also end up in the history, therefore executing both rules

Comment: First, don't use rules they will only make your life miserable. Second, use `ON CONFLICT` and a trigger to write to the history file.